# 32 bit kernel compiling using make-kpkg on a 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 failed

Tags: kernel, cross-compiling, gnu-make

i tried to compile a 32 bit kernel using make-kpkg for the atom machine on a
64 bit ubuntu server machine but it failed and get the following error message:

```
====== making target debian/stamp/conf/kernel-conf [new prereqs: ]======
make   CROSS_COMPILE=i686-linux-gnu- ARCH=i386 \
                    oldconfig;
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/huangmianbo/src/linux_3.18.20-rtai-5.2'
scripts/kconfig/conf --oldconfig Kconfig
#
# configuration written to .config
#
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/huangmianbo/src/linux_3.18.20-rtai-5.2'
make   CROSS_COMPILE=i686-linux-gnu- ARCH=i386 prepare
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/huangmianbo/src/linux_3.18.20-rtai-5.2'
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 25: i686-linux-gnu-gcc: command not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: i686-linux-gnu-gcc: command not found
make[2]: i686-linux-gnu-gcc: Command not found
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 25: i686-linux-gnu-gcc: command not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: i686-linux-gnu-gcc: command not found
make[2]: i686-linux-gnu-gcc: Command not found
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
/bin/sh: 1: i686-linux-gnu-gcc: not found
Kbuild:35: recipe for target 'kernel/bounds.s' failed
make[3]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
Makefile:980: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
make[2]: *** [prepare0] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/huangmianbo/src/linux_3.18.20-rtai-5.2'
debian/ruleset/targets/common.mk:194: recipe for target 'debian/stamp/conf/kernel-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [debian/stamp/conf/kernel-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/huangmianbo/src/linux_3.18.20-rtai-5.2'
/usr/share/kernel-package/ruleset/minimal.mk:93: recipe for target 'debian/stamp/conf/minimal_debian' failed
make: *** [debian/stamp/conf/minimal_debian] Error 2
Failed to create a ./debian directory:  at /usr/bin/make-kpkg line 970.
```

I used to compile the 32 bit kernel on my 32 bit virtual machine successfully.
but the time of compiling on a virtual machine is costly. so i decided to compile
it on the 64 bit machine. And i had set the make-kpkg parameter like this:

```
sudo make-kpkg --initrd kernel_image -j10 --arch i386 --cross-compile ""
```

but it still got the above error message and the "i686-linux-gnu-gcc" could not be
found by apt-get .

Comment: For cross-compile you need to set up a **toolchain**. `i686-linux-gnu-gcc` is a part of this toolchain.

Comment: how to set up a toolchain? apt-get install ?

Comment: Yes, you may install the toolchain via `apt install`. You may easily find which package contains the needed file: https://packages.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: do you konw what items to apt-get install ?  my os is ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: i had to upgrade my linux server from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS to install the 32 bits compiler tool-chain @Tsyvarev